# Select a date into bootstrap datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker, css-selectors

To create an e2e test, I have to select a date in a datepicker bootstrap with the inspector but I don’t know how to do it.
My goal is to click on a date number to complete the input.
When I inspect the datepicker, I get this from the inspector:

[image]

And here's the datepicker:

[image]

Apologize for my bad english

EDIT:
Sorry if I’m not clear, I want to select a date (any date) in the inspector so I can use a selector in the test I have to write.

For example, my test must say:

"When I click on a particular date, then the datepicker disappears"

My problem is I can’t inspect the datepicker

Comment: We don't understand  exactly what you ask for. And never give us code in pictures. Just place the code always into your question.

Comment: Please, attach your code, it's not clear what exactly the problem is.
Please, check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article to write a correct question.